# Optimizar y simplificar como creo elementos dinámicamente con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy utilizando para crear una actividad, una función que contiene numerosos bucles ya que toda la información se encuentra en varios arrays, y estoy creando elementos a medida que los recorro, asignando clases y ubicándolos en el HTML designado dinámicamente.

Este es un fragmento con uno de los bucles como ejemplo. La idea es simplificar como creo los elementos, clases, etc sin emplear jQuery o lo mínimo posible. ¿Se puede optimizar?

```
//Recorremos el arrays que contiene el objeto 'presenter.configuration.standardPage'
    for (let a = 0, b = 1; a < presenter.configuration.standardPage.length; a++, b++) {
        let checkControl = presenter.configuration.standardPage[a]['Page type'],
            pageWrapper = document.createElement('div'),
            titleDiv = document.createElement('div'),
            titlePar = document.createElement('p'),
            titleNode = document.createTextNode(presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].title1),
            textDiv = document.createElement('div'),
            textPar = document.createElement('p'),
            aux = {};

        pageWrapper.className = 'docu-wrapper-page-style ' + presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].id1;
        pageWrapper.dataset.page = 'num' + presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].pos1;
        titleDiv.className = 'docu-title-div';
        titleDiv.dataset.page = 'num' + presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].pos1;
        textDiv.className = 'docu-text-div';

        titlePar.appendChild(titleNode);
        titleDiv.appendChild(titlePar);
        pageWrapper.appendChild(titleDiv);

        textPar.innerHTML = presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].description1;    
        textDiv.appendChild(textPar);
        pageWrapper.appendChild(textDiv);

        // Añade un input para escribir texto   
        if (checkControl === 'Text input') {
            let inputDiv = document.createElement('div'),
                titlePar = document.createElement('p'),
                input = document.createElement('textarea');

            input.rows = presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].inputSize1;
            input.className = 'standard-input';
            input.cols = '58';
            input.placeholder = presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].placeholder1;

            pageWrapper.appendChild(input);
        }
        // Añade una imagen como anexo
        if (checkControl === 'Image') {
            let imageDiv = document.createElement('div'),
                titlePar = document.createElement('p'),
                img = document.createElement('img');

            img.src = presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].image1;
            imageDiv.className = 'page-image-style';

            imageDiv.appendChild(img);
            pageWrapper.appendChild(imageDiv);
        }    

        // Clonamos el div del título para llevarlo a otro lado    
        let titleClon = $(titleDiv).clone();
        titleClon.addClass('tabs-left-style tabs-button' + presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].pos1).removeClass('docu-title-div');

        // Metemos en el objeto declarado previamente el HTML del documento creado, el botón y lo insertamos en otro objeto
        aux['wrapper'] = $(pageWrapper);
        aux['clon'] = $(titleClon);

        presenter.list['page' + presenter.configuration.standardPage[a].pos1] = aux;
    }
```

Comment: Utiliza componentes con Vue.js por ejemplo y te estará más simplificado

Comment: Lamentablemente no puedo optar por librerías externas, debo fabricarme todo a 'medida'. No digo que mi código esté erróneo, que no lo está, pero me chirría ver tanto document.createElement, una y otra vez...

Comment: Otra opción son los webcomponents, https://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/ pero firefox y safari no son muy compatibles, sino no te queda otra que como lo estás haciendo

Comment: Pero es como comentas, dada la 'compatibilidad', mejor pecar de cautos. Definitivamente vía Javascript puro, no hay más alternativas verdad?

Comment: Qué yo conozca no :/

Comment: Lo único que veo que puedas hacer és la de dividir tu codigo en funciones mas pequeñas, nada más. De esa forma se lee todo siempre mejor.